# Could Not Load Type From Assembly on unused package version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ninject

I have a C# project that I just pulled down from version control on a new machine. I have all the dependencies installed in the project and when I try to run it I get to my dependency injection initialization (ninject) an `System.TypeLoadException` error on an internal library. The error says that it cannot load version 5.3.1.0 of the library, but I am not using that version. In my Web.config I am pointing to 5.4.5.0 and in my machine config I am pointing to version 4.9.1.0 - neither of which the error mentions. I search the project for the version that the error mentions and get nothing as well.

Is there anywhere else for me to look for this reference?

Comment: Is it in the `bin` directory?

Comment: It's not, I checked that too.